# Realistic Car Headlights

Tags: lighting, volumetrics, photorealism

I was trying to create some realistic lighting for a car render and I am having a bad time creating the volumetrics for the headlights. Some of the renders looked very noisy and in general really unrealistic.

I hope I'll get some help here ;)

**References**
 [image: Reference]

**Render**
 [image: Render]

Comment: please add your images to the question and any reference photos that clearly show what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @rob Images uplaoded!!!

Comment: does this help? https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/152545/pixelated-light-cone-near-source-with-eevee/152632#152632

Comment: @rob nope. The noisy image isn't my only problem. I need to find out how to create those realistic volumetrics because those ruin the whole render.  *Also I am using cycles

Comment: I think I would set up another scene (Blender can switch between multiple scenes) lose the car and just concentrate on creating a lighting domain and getting the light cones to do what you need then render that separately and combine in the compositor. There are lots of tutorials around volumetrics for Blender, try and find 2.8 ones.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check them.